# Разделить строку на массив

Tags: php

Допустим есть строка $string вида:

```
Ланягин Игорь Анатольевич
р. таджикиста г.стерлитамак ул. маркса 102-14 
тел.:
(909) 333-33-33
```

Необходимо каждую строчку записать в массив.
Делал так:

```
$msv = explode("<br>", $string)
```

и так:

```
$msv = explode("/n", $string);
```

Как правильно разделять в таких ситуациях?
Или допустим как разделить на 2 части, где разделителем будет `"тел.:"` ?

Нашел ошибку. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

1) `<br />` не сработает, если этих символов нет.
2) Не `/n`, а `\n`.
3) Если строка статичная, то можно так: `explode('тел:.', $string);`, если динамическая, то через регулярные выражения: `preg_split('!тел:\.!', $string);`.